# Remove Datagriview row in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to remove rows from my Datagridview. This is my Datagridview

[image]

And this is the code i use to remove rows

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Column28"].Value) < 2 )
    {
        dataGridView.Rows.Remove(row);
    }
    else
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Column29"].Value) < 6)
        {
            dataGridView.Rows.Remove(row);
        }
    }
}
```

But this is the result i get:

[image]

Where is the error?

Comment: What is the issue? And what is your expectation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `foreach` statement is used to iterate through the collection to get the information that you want, but *can* not be used to *add* or *remove* items from the source collection to avoid unpredictable side effects.

If we need to add or remove items from the source collection, use a `for` loop.

```
for(int i =0; i< DataGridView.Rows.Count; i++))
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32( DataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["Column28"].Value) < 2 )
    {
        DataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
        i--;
    }
    else
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["Column29"].Value) < 6)
        {
            DataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
            i--; 
        }
    }
}
```